# Safari Extension not geting session Info

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, safari

I create simple safari extension which used simple js file where i send request on my own server and check user session is set or not. In my extension code when i send Ajax call to my own server it get other information but can't get user session while user is logged in.Here is my code:

```
var storeUrl = window.location.href;
$(document).ready(function()
{
var store = storeUrl.replace("http://",'');
store = store.replace("/",'');
jQuery.ajax({

    url: 'https://www.karmora.com/checkstore/' + store, 
    context: document.body,
    error: function(data, transport) {

    },
    success: function(data) {
        var storeData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.info(storeData);  
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Looks like you're running into the AJAX cross-domain restriction.

Comment: #Barmar i fix all the cross domain restriction.

Comment: only problem is not getting session variable.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.